# Handling application specific actions after device is waking up from sleep

Tags: android

I am storing all application specific data in my db.
I want to perform different actions when

- Application is first time opened after device wake up from sleep
- Application is opened 2nd/more times after waking up from sleep

How can i do this?
e.g

- Camera is opened after device wake up - for first time - my application will ask for password
- camera is opened 2nd time i wont ask for password
- whatsapp is opened after device wake up - for first time - my application will ask for password
- whatsapp is opened 2nd time i wont ask for password

Answer (score 0):

Implement your `if-else` on a `Service` with `BroadcastReceiver` that will run everytime the device is turned on, example :

```
<receiver android:name="com.example.MyBroadcastReceiver">  
    <intent-filter>  
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />  
    </intent-filter>  
</receiver>
```

And dont forget to add the permission :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
```

Comment: Hey, that will be fine..bt it wont be app specific like suppose i am adding a flag which will be set true when opened first time from sleep. then  i launch camera, i set it as false. Next, when i open whatsapp , even though i need that as true, it will be false. because its the common flag...n thats teh issue..